# Import data from .csv file into Sqlite table in Qt

Tags: sql, sqlite, qt, csv, import

I am able to get my application to download 3 .csv files from a secured FTP with the help of the Qt Network Download example, create a local Sqlite database along with 3 tables that will eventually hold the information that is contained within the csv files.

The following came from a blog posting about importing csv files in Qt and the output insert statements seem correct but the data does not seem to make it into the table.

```
    void speciesinformation::populateTable()
{
    QFile f("species_list_dos_utf8.csv");

    if(f.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly| QIODevice::Text)){
        QSqlQuery que;
        QTextStream ts (&f);

        //Travel through the csv file
        while(!ts.atEnd()){
            QString req = "INSERT INTO species_list VALUES (";
            // split every line
            QStringList line = ts.readLine().split('\n');

            /*for every values on a line,
                   append it to the INSERT request*/
            for(int i=0; i<line .length ();++i){
                req.append(line.at(i));
                req.append(",");
            }
            req.chop(1); // remove the trailing comma
            req.append(");"); // close the "VALUES([...]" with a ");"
            que.exec(req);
            qDebug() << req;
        }
    }
}
```

and the output reads:

> "INSERT INTO species_list VALUES (Perennial
> sowthistle,Asteraceae,Aster,Sonchus,361,Plantae,arvensis,Herbs);"
> "INSERT INTO species_list VALUES (Thorny
> olive,Elaeagnaceae,Oleaster,Elaeagnus,363,Plantae,pungens,Shrubs);"
> ...etc

When I open up DBBrowser (Sqlite) to look at the database, nothing appears in the species_list table. I have the database creation and the table creation in separate functions within my .cpp.

I have another test function (below) but I receive an QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
error message.

```
void speciesinformation::populateSpeciesTable()
{
    //open file
    QFile fspecies("species_list_dos_utf8.csv");
    if (!fspecies.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qDebug() << fspecies.errorString();
    }

    QStringList wordList;
    while (!fspecies.atEnd()) {
        QByteArray fields = fspecies.readAll();
        wordList.append(fields.split(',').first());
    }
    qDebug() << wordList;

    QSqlQuery popSpecies;
    popSpecies.prepare("INSERT INTO species_list(cname, family, fdetail, genus, id, kingdom, species, habit) values(:one, :two, :three, :four, :five, :six, :seven, :eight)");
    popSpecies.bindValue(":one",popSpecies.value(0).toChar());
    popSpecies.bindValue(":two",popSpecies.value(1).toChar());
    popSpecies.bindValue(":three",popSpecies.value(2).toChar());
    popSpecies.bindValue(":four",popSpecies.value(3).toChar());
    popSpecies.bindValue(":five",popSpecies.value(4).toChar());
    popSpecies.bindValue(":six",popSpecies.value(5).toChar());
    popSpecies.bindValue(":seven",popSpecies.value(6).toChar());
    popSpecies.bindValue(":eight",popSpecies.value(7).toChar());


    if(!popSpecies.exec())
    {
        qDebug()<< popSpecies.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

I have read the Qt documentation and other forums but I cannot seem to copy the data from the csv files into the Sqlite tables. Any examples or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you get from query in first part of the code ? .. when you do  `INSERT INTO species_list VALUES( ..)`  .. are you sure you inserting values for all columns ? the error in second code part is that you are binding to the query from query result ?!  `popSpecies.value(0)` should not appear in query binding .. may be you want something like `popSpecies.bindValue(":one",wordList.at(0).toChar());`

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thank you for your response. The first part I do not receive any error messages in the application output - it just lists out all the insert statements for each row.

Comment: Mohammad, I just want to say that your comment about the bindValue section has helped me tremendously! I ended up focusing on that section I tried changing it to `popSpecies.bindValue(":one",wordList.at(0).toChar());` but I was receiving an error message so I modified it to this `popSpecies.bindValue(":one",wordList.value(0).toUtf8());` and it does in fact place "cname" in my database table! It seems like something may be wrong with the wordlist though because it seems to only be reading the word "cname" from the file (which is the first word that appears in the file).

Comment: For the first part , you need to check the error explicitly after exec the query .. `lastError()` should tell what went wrong!

Comment: Understood - thank you! I will post a comment here if I run into an issue with the error. I certainly appreciate your time.

Comment: Mohammad, I just wanted to say thank you again - my app now successfully populates the table with the .csv data!